# How to add foreign key in table using existing column without losing data in django with sqlite3?

Tags: django, sqlite

I want to alter some tables that have IntegerField type into a foreign key without losing any data. so, How can I do that in both sqlite3 and  Django when I do makemigrations command?

this is models looks like:

```
class Sentences(models.Model):
    actor_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    film_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Tokens(models.Model):
    word_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sentence_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Actors(models.Model):
    ...

class Words(models.Model):
    ...

class Films(models.Model):
    ...
```

every **_id** has IntegerField in the first place is referred to the actual id from another table but instead, I want to modify it to become ForeignKey instead of IntegerField how I do that modification?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django change an existing field to foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66803323/django-change-an-existing-field-to-foreign-key)

Answer (score 0):

id is a primary key for every table. It has unique values for each row. Foreign Key is the column that refers to the primary key of another table. To define Foreign Key refer the model name like

```
class Tokens(models.Model):
    word = models.ForeignKey(Words, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sentence = models.ForeignKey(Sentence, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ..........
```

After migrating your relation (Table) "Tokens" will have two columns 1. word_id and 2. sentence_id
Refer : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: This is false. This doesn't create a migration that will preserve the column.

Comment: I am marking as duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66803323/django-change-an-existing-field-to-foreign-key