# Django change an existing field to foreign key

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-migrations

I have a Django model that used to look like this:

```py
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer_id = models.IntegerField()
```

There is another model called `Manufacturer` that the `id` field refers to. However, I realized that it would be useful to use Django's built-in foreign key functionality, so I changed the model to this:

```py
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
```

This change appears to work fine immediately, queries work without errors, but when I try to run migrations, Django outputs the following:

```
- Remove field manufacturer_id from car
- Add field manufacturer to car
```

Doing this migration would clear all the existing relationships in the database, so I don't want to do that. I don't really want any migrations at all, since queries like `Car.objects.get(manufacturer__name="Toyota")` work fine. I would like a proper database foreign key constraint, but it's not a high priority.

So my question is this: Is there a way to make a migration or something else that allows me to convert an existing field to a foreign key? I cannot use `--fake` since I need to reliably work across dev, prod, and my coworkers' computers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do data migration

1. add new field
2. do a data migration https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations
3. remove old field

I am not sure, there might be another solution where you can rename the field to name you want to, then alter the filed to new type (do a migration)

```
operations = [
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='car',
            old_name='manufacturer_id',
            new_name='manufacturer',
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='car',
            name='manufacturer',
            field=ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True,  
                  on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE
            ),
    ]
```

Answer (score -1):

I've faced the same issue today.
Can be done without renaming an existing field or dropping existing column.

1. Update the initial migration with CreateModel operation

```
...
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="Car",
            fields=[
                (
                    "manufacturer",
                    models.ForeignKey(
                        blank=True,
                        null=True,
                        on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.DO_NOTHING,
                        db_constraint=False,
                        db_index=False,
                        to="Manufacturer",
                    ),
                ),
```

2. Check that `db_constraint` and `db_index` are `True` on `Car.manufacturer` field of `Car` model. True is a default value if the fields not set.
3. Run `./manage.py makemigrations` that generates `AlterField` migration with required constraint and index on `Car.manufacturer_id`.

The first step won't effect db consistency because the generated DDL will be the same for `IntegerField` and `ForeignKey` with `db_constaint=False` and `db_index=False`
and the second migration adds missing constraint and index.

You can check that with `./manage.py sqlmigrate app migration` command