# how to change an existing char field to a foreign key in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, orm, database-migration, django-migrations

I had this model

```
class Order(models.Model):
 ...
 discount_code = models.CharField()
```

but at some point in development we decided to move from text only discount_codes to a Model with code, percentage, start and end dates etc. Which meant we had to update to a foreign key

```
class Order(models.Model):
 ...
 discount_code = models.ForeignKey(to=DiscountCode, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
```

during this time a few hundred orders were generated and naturally some had discount codes. When it came to running migrations we werent able to, simply because char is not a foreign key.

So I decided to update the migration to handle moving from char to an object but it still fails.

Here's the migration file

```
# Generated by Django 3.2 on 2022-09-20 05:13

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
from datetime import date


def create_discount_objects(apps, schema_editor):
    Order = apps.get_model('orders', 'Order')
    DiscountCode = apps.get_model('orders', 'DiscountCode')

    # Get a list of unique discount codes from the existing orders
    discount_codes = Order.objects.exclude(discount_code=None).order_by('discount_code').values_list('discount_code', flat=True).distinct('discount_code')

    # Create new Discount objects for each discount code
    discount_objects = []
    for code in discount_codes:
        if code is not None:
            discount_objects.append(DiscountCode(code=code, percentage=10.0, start_date=date(2023,4,20), end_date=date(2023,4,20)))
    DiscountCode.objects.bulk_create(discount_objects)

    # Update the existing orders to link them to the corresponding Discount objects
    for order in Order.objects.all():
        if order.discount_code is not None:
            discount = DiscountCode.objects.get(code=order.discount_code)
            order.discount_code = discount
            order.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('orders', '0012_alter_requiredpart_part_quantity'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='DiscountCode',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('code', models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)),
                ('percentage', models.FloatField()),
                ('status', models.CharField(choices=[('active', 'Active'), ('expired', 'Expired'), ('inactive', 'Inactive')], default='active', max_length=10)),
                ('start_date', models.DateField()),
                ('end_date', models.DateField()),
                ('notes', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(create_discount_objects),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='order',
            name='discount_code',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='orders.discountcode'),
        ),
    ]
```

This is the error I get when running `python manage.py migrate`

```
TypeError: Tried to update field orders.Order.discount_code with a model instance, <DiscountCode: DiscountCode object (85)>. Use a value compatible with CharField.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S This did not help [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66803323/django-change-an-existing-field-to-foreign-key)

Comment: imho, if `DiscountCode` table is empty I see it in less complicated way: 1) select `DISTINCT` values of `discount_code`, populate the `DiscountCode` table (maybe by a separate preceding migration) 2) update `discount_id` based on `discount_code` value in `Order` table with a single update statement/query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suggestion to do this in steps (only basics envolved  ... no complex manual migration modifications):

1. define model `Discount`
2. define new ForeignKey in model `Order` with temporary name like:

```
discount_code_fk = models.ForeignKey(...)
```

3. do migrations
4. loop: create all `Discount` instances from codes as you do and assign `Discount` instances to `discount_code_fk`
5. remove `discount_code` from model `Discount`
6. migrate
7. rename `discount_code_fk` to `discount_code` in model `Discount`
8. migrate